# winform Close self plus another WebBrowserControl

Tags: c#, winforms

i know i could search proccessId / name of running tasks and kill processes i need .

though till now i was not developing schedualed tasks / self executble Applications,

so i didn't need to know how to make the application close itself after execition

trying to close *everything* (including WebDriver) via `Application.Exit` + OR  `this.Close()`
right after i have got what i was looking for. mission Complete . 
please close ... no more work for you . 
but mr . Program.cs still needs somthing from Form1.
saying somthing about 
Cannot access a disposed object.
Object name: 'Form1'.

any combination of both was returning in some point an exeption error 
(from program.cs ) even though mission complete . no more code was requested .(?) by me..atleast.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using OpenQA.Selenium;
using OpenQA.Selenium.IE;
using System.IO;

namespace HT_R_WbBrows2
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {


    public IeEnginGenerator Iengn = new IeEnginGenerator();
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        //setLogView(View.Details);

        string extractededVal = Iengn.ExtractPageValue(Iengn.itrfWebEng);
        string flnm = @" the directory path to file --> \dolarRate.asp";



        File.WriteAllText(fn, extractededVal);

        this.Close();
        Application.Exit();
    }





public  class IeEnginGenerator
{

    private string directory = Environment.CurrentDirectory;///Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().CodeBase);


    public   IWebDriver IwebEngine;
    public List<string> ListElementsInnerHtml = new List<string>();
    public HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument Dnetdoc = new HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument();

    #region <<=========== setupDriver ============>>
    public  string  ExtractPageValue(IWebDriver DDriver, string url="") 
    {
        if(string.IsNullOrEmpty(url))
        url = @"http://www.boi.org.il/he/Markets/ExchangeRates/Pages/Default.aspx";
        var service = InternetExplorerDriverService.CreateDefaultService(directory);
        service.LogFile = directory + @"\seleniumlog.txt";
        service.LoggingLevel = InternetExplorerDriverLogLevel.Trace;

        var options = new InternetExplorerOptions();
        options.IntroduceInstabilityByIgnoringProtectedModeSettings = true;

        DDriver = new InternetExplorerDriver(service, options, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(60));
        DDriver.Navigate().GoToUrl(url);

        Dnetdoc.LoadHtml(DDriver.PageSource);
        string Target = Dnetdoc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//table//tr")[1].ChildNodes[7].InnerText;
           //.Select(tr => tr.Elements("td").Select(td => td.InnerText).ToList())
           //.ToList();


        return  Math.Round(Convert.ToDouble(Target), 2).ToString();

        //return "";//Math.Round(Convert.ToDouble( TempTxt.Split(' ')[10]),2).ToString();

    }
    #endregion



}






}
}
```

Comment: Calling Close() in the form constructor is suicide.  It bombs because the Main() method in Program.cs is calling Application.Run() with a closed form.  The code makes little sense, you'll need to re-think this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why use a winform application? A Console application would probably suffice for what you are doing. Once Main() ends your app will close as well. Main() never ends in a winform app because of the applications runloop.

Edit:

Here would be the correct way to do this. You need to register to the forms Load event and run your code there, not in the constructor. You can't close a winform from inside a constructor.

Edit 2: Put this code in the Form1() constructor. Somewhere after InitializeComponent();

```
    this.Load += (sender,args)=>{ /*do all your work here*/  
     string extractededVal = Iengn.ExtractPageValue(Iengn.itrfWebEng);
     string flnm = @" the directory path to file --> \dolarRate.asp";
     File.WriteAllText(fn, extractededVal);
     Application.Exit(); 
  };
```

Comment: thanks . but i really hate Console . never even learned via this category , i know from my intuition i could do it simply via console app though i could think about finish it like that , even though i will i might do as told , what if i need it to be in a winform so i could in one mode (view maybe later i might add functionanllity ... etc) i know you must be right but ....can you tell mr' program.cs run form one only (condition) condition = mission not complete?

Comment: see the answer above. Put that code in your Form1() consrtructor

Comment: i did use Console App ...aventually, will work on this later (: , after some changes : therad is pointing to a `void` that executes a set of methods, then when finished using methods  iWebdriver.Close() , service Dispose(), no more running apps or parts of app are alive!